# Excel VBA Issue ... Value in Col A range determines next action - comparing two other Col values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stumped. Have been working on this forever. Need a routine to compute a value. In ColA range there is either a "v" or an "h" ... just trying to get the "v" logic working first.

Pretty straightforward. Can't get this function to work even a little bit. Would be greatly appreciative of any advice. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
Function CountFunction() As Integer

Dim ColA As Range, ColB As Range, ColJ As Range

Dim vResult As Integer
Dim Visitor As String

Set ColA = Range("A5:A20")
Set ColB = Range("B5:B20")
Set ColJ = Range("J5:J20")

Visitor = "v"
vResult = 0

For Each ColA In ColA.Range("A5:A20")
    For Each ColB In ColB.Range("B5:B20")
        For Each ColJ In ColJ.Range("J5:J20")
            If ColA.Cells.Value = Visitor Then
                If ColB.Cells.Value = ColJ.Cells.Value Then
                    vResult = vResult + 1
                Else
                    vResult = vResult + 0
                End If
            Else
                If ColB.Cells.Value = ColJ.Cells.Value Then
                    vResult = vResult + 0
                Else
                    vResult = vResult + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

CountFunction = vResult

End Function
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What is it not doing that it should be doing?  (It appears that you are doing a count of "v" in column A and multiplying that by the number of values in column B that have a match somewhere in column J.  Is that what you want, or do you want something else?)

Answer (score 1):

"Pretty straightforward." 
No, it's not :]

You can replace

```
Set ColA = Range("A5:A20")
Set ColB = Range("B5:B20")
Set ColJ = Range("J5:J20")
```

with

```
Set ColA = Range("A1")
Set ColB = Range("A1")
Set ColJ = Range("A1")
```

or better, replace

```
For Each ColA In ColA.Range("A5:A20")
    For Each ColB In ColB.Range("B5:B20")
        For Each ColJ In ColJ.Range("J5:J20")
```

with

```
For Each ColA In Range("A5:A20")
    For Each ColB In Range("B5:B20")
        For Each ColJ In Range("J5:J20")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (but I am really guessing) that what you are trying to achieve is:

```
Function CountFunction() As Integer

    Dim ColA As Range

    Dim vResult As Integer
    Dim Visitor As String

    Visitor = "v"
    vResult = 0

    For Each ColA In Range("A5:A20")
        If ColA.Value = Visitor Then
            If ColA.Offset(0, 1).Value = ColA.Offset(0, 9).Value Then
                vResult = vResult + 1
            End If
        Else
            If ColA.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ColA.Offset(0, 9).Value Then
                vResult = vResult + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    CountFunction = vResult

End Function
```

**Update following comment:**

If you wish to use this as a UDF, I would suggest passing in the three different ranges you are using (in your example "A5:A20", "B5:B20", and "J5:J20") plus the value of `Visitor` (as I suspect you are going to modify the code based on whether you are doing the calculations for a value of "v" or "h").

So modify the function to be:

```
Function CountFunction(rngA As Range, rngB As Range, rngX As Range, Visitor As String) As Variant

    Dim vResult As Integer
    Dim r As Long

    vResult = 0

    If rngA.Rows.Count <> rngB.Rows.Count Or _
       rngA.Rows.Count <> rngX.Rows.Count Then
        CountFunction = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    For r = 1 To rngA.Rows.Count
        If rngA.Cells(r, 1).Value = Visitor Then
            If rngB.Cells(r, 1).Value = rngX.Cells(r, 1).Value Then
                vResult = vResult + 1
            End If
        Else
            If rngB.Cells(r, 1).Value <> rngX.Cells(r, 1).Value Then
                vResult = vResult + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    CountFunction = vResult

End Function
```

and call it as

```
=CountFunction($A5:$A20,$B5:$B20,J5:J20,"v")
```

(Obviously, I hope, the ranges can be adjusted to suit whatever range is appropriate.)

The function does very limited error checking - it just checks that each of the three ranges have the same number of rows.  But it doesn't check for number of columns, or validity of values, etc.

Comment: YowE3K, thanks! That works. I am so appreciative! Now one additional question. If I want that second offset (0, 9) to be a variable that I feed into the function, how can I restate (0, 9), pass the Column position into the function and make it work? I'm going to need to copy/paste this function to other columns across the spreadsheet. Thanks again. Your assistance was excellent. Tom

Comment: @TominFlorida - I've updated the answer to show how to pass the three ranges, and the value of `Visitor` as parameters.

Comment: Perfect. You are a life saver. Thanks for taking the time to help. This is so perfect for what I needed. Thanks! Tom